# Defining @property

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, abstract-class, abc

I have problem in defining a getter by using `@property` in concrete class. Here is the python code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, value1):
        self.v1 = value1

    @abstractproperty
    def v1(self):
        pass

class concrete(abstract):
    def __init__(self, value1):
        super(concrete, self).__init__(value1)

    @property
    def v1(self):
        return self.v1
```

Then test the code and get this error:

```
test_concrete = concrete("test1")
test_concrete.v1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-eb896d7ec1c9> in <module>()
----> 1 test_concrete = concrete("test1")
      2 test_concrete.v1

<ipython-input-189-bf15021022d3> in __init__(self, value1)
     11 class concrete(abstract):
     12     def __init__(self, value1):
---> 13         super(concrete, self).__init__(value1)
     14 
     15     @property

<ipython-input-189-bf15021022d3> in __init__(self, value1)
      3 
      4     def __init__(self, value1):
----> 5         self.v1 = value1
      6 
      7     @abstractproperty

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Basically I intend to set `v1` as a read-only attribute.

I am used to using the same name for the attribute and its getter function, but it seems that I cannot do it if the class inherited from an abstract class.

I found a workaround by using different name for the getter function `v1` as `get_v1`:

```
class abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, value1):
        self.v1 = value1

    @abstractproperty
    def get_v1(self):
        pass

class concrete(abstract):
    def __init__(self, value1):
        super(concrete, self).__init__(value1)

    @property
    def get_v1(self):
        return self.v1
```

Is there a better workaround for this problem?

Comment: A common practice is naming private attributes like `_v1`.

Comment: You haven't actually provided a setter for the property, so it's currently read-only. Also, you can't give the backing attribute the same name as the property, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with abstract classes. This is a namespace issue; the property object and instance attributes occupy the same namespace, you cannot have both an instance attribute and a property use the exact same name.

You are trying to access the *property* by using `self.v1 = ...` and `v1` is not magically an instance attribute just because you are accessing it from a method on the instance, that is *always* going to be the property object.

In the same vein, your property getter will cause an infinite loop:

```
@property
def v1(self):
    return self.v1
```

because `self.v1` *is* the property object, not an instance attribute.

Use a different name for the actual storage:

```
def __init__(self, value1):
    self._v1 = value1

@property
def v1(self):
    return self._v1
```

Note that you cannot have truly private attributes in Python (like you can in C# or Java); the leading underscore on names is only a convention and a determined coder can always access your instance state directly. A `property` object does not change this.

Comment: Thank you. It works when I set the attribute as _v1 instead.